# Binding does not work MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following implementation where I am getting age and binding it. However, no matter what I did, it did not update on UI and also for some reason it did not even hit the getter.

**ViewModel**

```
public void Initialize()
{
   Age = 33;
}

public double _age;  
public double Age
{
  get { return _age ; }
  set
  {
    _age = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Age);
   }          
}
```

**xml**

```
<TextView
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 local:MvxBind="Text Age" />
```

Comment: Can you access the ViewModel within the`Fragment` or `Activity`? Any errors in the output window?

Comment: There is no error in the output window. I can access View model in  the Fragment

Comment: The **Model** code is actually a model or a ViewModel?

Comment: The method `Initialize()` do you call it yourself? The default initialization method is `Init()` not `Initialize()`

Comment: I am calling it my self in the View Model constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly, without more context. The code looks right. For the binding to work you need to follow the correct naming conventions so that MvvmCross can associate all the necessary bits and pieces with one another. So in this case, if your view is called AgeDisplayView, your view model must be called AgeDisplayViewModel. Your view must also override the OnCreate method and use it to set the ContentView to the layout file that contains the MvxBind instructions (e.g. SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AgeDisplayViewLayout).

That would be the first place I'd look.